# cannot access db from script

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to delete a row from a table in my database from a script. Perhaps this isn't the easiest way but I think it should be possible. I'm trying the following:

```
from stemewebapp import app
from stemewebapp.models import Job, db
import sys

#
# Check arguments
#
if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print 'USAGE: %s <job uuid>' % (sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(-1)
job_uuid = sys.argv[1]

#
# Do everything in context
#
with app.test_request_context():

    #
    # Get job
    #
    query = db.session.query(Job).filter_by(uuid=job_uuid)
    #query = Job.query.filter_by(uuid=job_uuid)
    if 1 != query.count():
        raise RuntimeError('Got more than one job by UUID.')

    #
    # Delete from database
    #
    db.session.delete(query.first())
    db.session.commit()
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
OperationalError: (OperationalError) no such table: job u'SELECT count(*) AS count_1 \nFROM (SELECT job.id AS job_id, job.creation_date AS job_creation_date, job.name AS job_name, job.uuid AS job_uuid, job.pid AS job_pid, job.completed AS job_completed \nFROM job \nWHERE job.uuid = ?) AS anon_1' ('743d952f-9cfc-4efc-bfa5-58da67c4a131',)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the right way.

Sqlalchemy provides method with name `one` on query object.

```
     try:
         obj = db.session.query(Job).filter_by(uuid=job_uuuid).one()
     except NoResultFound:
         raise
     except MultipleResultsFound:
         raise RuntimeError('Got more than one job by UUID.')
     else:  
         db.session.delete(obj)
         db.session.commit()
```

One() fetches only one result and if there are multiple results then raises that exception.

Error suggests table does not exist. Check if you are accessing wrong database or you have forgotten to intialize database. Current information is insufficient to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the one method. I think both ways work.

Comment: Just found out I needed to configure flask with same settings as when it is run in Apache. Thanks for pointer. Obvious when you think about it but why did it not complain it could not find the database in the first place?

Comment: @John You should not use query.count(). You are first issuing a count query and then another query to actually access object whereas simple query.one() will do with a  single and more efficient query. Moreover using exceptions the code is more readable and maintainable!

Comment: Well OK fair points but I have an improvement over your method then: just leave out the try: except: parts and let the exceptions propagate upwards. That seems more readable.